# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier images data json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i want get images from data json and this is my code :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {    
     var dmJSON = "";
     $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {    
         var html = '';

         for(var i = 0; i < data.feed.data.length; i++){    
             html += '<div>';
             html += data.feed.data[i].message
             html += '<br>';
             html +='<img alt="" src='data.feed.data[i].picture' />';
             html += '</div>';
         }    
         $("#news").append(html);
     });    
 });
```

get error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: If you read the entirety of that error message (it doesn't stop at `Unexpected identifier`) it'll tell you exactly where your syntax error is at - file and line number.

Answer (score 3):

Do concatenation properly,

```
html += '<img alt="" src=' + data.feed.data[i].picture + ' />';
//-------------------------^ --------------------------^
```

Comment: @aligassan Glad to help! By the way, consider clicking the tick mark present with this answer. It may help the future visitors to find this answer has helped you. But this is not a compulsion. :)